# Facebook connect with asp.net membership

Tags: facebook

I want to implement Facebook connect on my website and I want it to be integrated with asp.net membership.

what I have so far: I do have the normal asp.net membership with rules and everything. and I have managed to communicate with Facebook to get the user's data. and I have created the Facebook app needed for that.

what is needed: I need to give my website users the ability to login with their Facebook accounts, and to be able add reviews and comment on things on the website. Note: only registered users can write comments and reviews.

but I am not sure where to go from here? should I store the users Facebook data (user name, email, id, etc..) in my database or what? and how the app can tell that the users are logged in when they uses Facebook account?

Answer (score 0):

> should I store the users Facebook data (user name, email, id, etc..) in my database or what?

Just create them a “normal” account with the data you received from Facebook.

> and how the app can tell that the users are logged in when they uses Facebook account?

Log the normal account in, if a user is using Facebook login and already has one.

Comment: "Log the normal account in, if a user is using Facebook login and already has one." can you explain how to do that? what do you mean by log the normal account in, how to do it? they just press the facebook login button!

Comment: I don’t know how your page’s system works internally, but you should have a method/component to log a user from within your script logic. If you don’t have such a method – write one.